# 404 Not found when MVC application deployed

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm a newbie to Stack Overflow so here goes - I have an .NET MVC application which I've created some extra pages and additions to which works fine when I run it locally through Visual Studio which is running as `http://localhost:49204`.

However now I have deployed it to our server which can be accessed through `http://appdev` none of the additions are pulling through and I get a 404 error message when I try to access them. I've opened up firebug and tracked the URL that is being access and the parameters are the same the only difference its the servername /port number.

The files do exist on the server. I have attached screenshots of the GET request from both the server and localhost

It is important to note its only the additions that are not working, the other pages which have not been changed work correctly - very strange.

Appreciate any help you guys can suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Start by putting an test.html with hello world text in your project it to verify the path and settings of iis. 

404 is not a programming error and really doesen't fit here.

Comment: Hi, I've done that URL is http://appdev/test/test.html. The details of the 404 message are - "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://appdev/test/api/Rights?Username=testuser No type was found that matches the controller named 'Rights'."

Comment: Did you hard-coded any url in the code? or is using Url.Action()?

Comment: Hi, its set as a variable in a javascript file - var SystemRightsURL  "api/Rights";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue. Do the following process to deploy the code. when you publish the code just go to the settings and select release mode in configuration dropdown and then publish it. It will resolve your problem. :-)

Comment: If you feel this answer is useful then please vote it. So that it can be helpful for others. Thank You